# How to replace string to lowercase with regex in SQL?

Tags: sql, regex, replace

I have a html source in DB.
How can I replace all uppercase symbols to lowercase on this(xxx) attribute?

Thank You.

Comment: what is you dbms? do you have tags with more then one attribute? you shoul edit your question and add more infomation.

Comment: I suggest you create a application for this that can parse the html (you can use html agility pack for this) and than change the text you need and write it back to the DB.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use  substring and lower() function like below

```
 select lower(SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX('<tagname xxx="UhYklioLLkhRRttyNN" />','=',-1),'/',1 ))
```

now for your case in place of string replace your column name
lets say your table column name is column1
then it would be

```
select lower( SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(column1,'=',-1),'/',1 )) from yourtable
```

Comment: Zaynul Abadin Tuhin I want to change to lowercase only the value of this attribute

Comment: @ArsenArm you want to "UhYklioLLkhRRttyNN" this as lower?

Comment: @ArsenArm check answer please

Answer (score 0):

Try this regex in your app.

Search for: `xxx=\"([A-Za-z]+)\"`

Replace with: `xxx="\L$1"`

https://regex101.com/r/4b054O/1/